Installing Material Studio on Linux (CentOs cluster) for a non-root user
I am a beginner and want to install Material Studio in CentOs (version 7) cluster. Is there anyone have detailed tutorial or information for installing Material Studio in linux?
My tries:
I used ssh to connect to the cluster and did as follows:

I unzipped the file with tar -xvzf
I chose allowed directory for installation.
I chose a directory for The BIOVIA License Pack.
Then I get this message:


this directory does not appear to contain a supported License Pack
installation. Would you like to install it to that location? [Y/n]

In this case, I selected "yes".

For the Gateway service, I do not exactly know What purpose is this option used for? So, I used "no" for the following message:
Do you want to start the Gateway service after installation?
If you want to configure security settings before starting or if you do not want to run the service, enter n (Y/n)

About the Apache, since I do not know it, I used "no" again!
Do you expect to require Apache?

Finally, I failed to instll with this error:


Running LicensePack installation...
/share/Materials Studio-2023-v23x64/MaterialsStudio2023/LicensePack/lp_setup: line 112: /share/Materials: No such file or directory 

WARNING: You have either chosen to cancel your installation, or an error has occurred.
Please Verify your usage is correct:

Usage: lp_setup [-silent] [-console] [-P licensepack.installLocation=<path>] [-V PRODUCT_LP_FILE=<path to lp_location file>] [Port@HostName] [ -C ] 

       -silent - installs the product in silent mode.
       -console - installs the product in console mode.
       -P licensepack.installLocation - allows the user to specify the location to install License Pack.
       -V PRODUCT_LP_FILE - write License Pack Install directory to file.
        Port@HostName - specify the port@hostname of the License Pack server.
       -C - to run License Pack Compatibility Mode on silent.
If usage is correct please refer to FAQ section of the LicensePack documentation or contact BIOVIA Support.
The LicensePack documentation index is called LicensePack.html and is located on the CD.
Return Code: 127
LicensePack installation failed


This looks like the space hasn't been escaped properly in "Materials Studio-2023-v23x64". Is lp_setup a script that you can examine? Also, what components are you actually wanting to install, if not the Gateway and Apache job server?

Thanks @PhilHasnip for your comment.  In the program directory, there is a file named as "install". I used './install' to run it and then above questions came subsequently. I am too beginner. Is there any material or video by which I can promote my understanding on installing a program on cluster through ssh?

It's usually best to avoid spaces in names. Did you specify the directory, or did it choose that automatically?

If you just want to run a simulation directly on your Linux machine, then you can just install the simulation software. If you want to launch a simulation and/or monitor its progress from another computer, then you'll need the Gateway.

Thanks @PhilHasnip for your brief and useful clarifications. Yes.  the directory was specified  automatically.
